# document.write() and .innerHTML not writing to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working to print the results of a JavaScript function to a webpage; but I'm stuck on the printing - both `document.write()` and `.innerHTML` aren't printing anything to my `div` with `id` "output". None of the code below is changing anything:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var print = document.getElementById("output");
    print.innerHTML = "hello world";
    document.write("hello");
</script>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: `document.write` is `document.wrong`. The `document.write` function tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead. (as other comment said, please post the script in the context of the HTML too)

Comment: Side note, even though you indeed probably should not be using `document.write` any time soon, if the statement "*None of the code below is changing anything:*" is correct, this is probably the sign of an error blocking the execution of your script. And the most probable error I can see in these three lines is *Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*, probably because at the time you try to get the element `#output`, it hasn't yet been parsed, probably because your `<script>` tag is at the top of your HTML markup, or at least prior to the `#output` element's tags.

Comment: Anyway, you will certainly find more information by looking at the *console*  of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no alternative to `document.write("");` function in javascript.

Comment: @Kimberly your script seems to be correct, please put   this script at the end of the file after closing of <body> tag i.e. after </body> if you are not.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the head-up about `document.write`, guys. I'm just trying `.innerHTML`, but it's looking like the problem is with the script tags themselves. I've tried them at the very end of the `</body>` tag and right after (but before the `</html>` tag.) Are there any other common errors I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel very silly for discovering my issue was a simple syntax issue, but I'll post this here with my answer and a few others for anyone having similar problems!

My issue was that I was using `getElementById` but had labelled my `div` with a `class`, not an `id`! What a silly mistake to make! It happens, though - I'm thankful for all these answers that helped me look more critically at my code.

Like other answers have stated, it's important for the `script` tags to be at the end of the document so that the page can render first before the scripts are run. It's also important to make sure you have `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` to clarify what kind of script you're using. And TIL that `document.write` is *not* a good feature for writing text to a web page because it erases everything else there!

I hope this and the other answers here help anyone trying to make their scripts work!

Answer (score 1):

Cause for your issue is div was not loaded when javascript was executing. You have put the javascript snippet on the top of the page. You can either put the javascript code snippets to the page bottom or organize code snippets as a JS function and call it.

```
<html>

    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        print = document.getElementById("output");
        print.innerHTML = "hello world";
        document.write("hello");
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: @88MPG Please re-consider about your comment because you had commented while I was editing the answer and the above code snippets is working and explaining the missing point of the above question

Comment: Thanks! I've tried my script tags after the `</body>` tag and it still doesn't seem to be working, but this is a good error to catch for others having a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I'm a bit crazy about jQuery, but it makes my life so much easier, considering how much easier it is to use. Instead of doing document.write("hello"); which totally clears the slate and overwrites everything.

Consider using this

`$(document.body).append('hello');` - it does the same function as `document.write()`, but it doesn't totally overwrite the document like `document.write()` does.

I know that this isn't the most efficient way to do this, but I couldn't find any good alternative in just plain javascript.

Comment: jQuery really does make life easier! The code segment you suggested works perfectly :) I'm using a separate JS document to run it, though - my script tags appear to not be working within the HTML document, and I do kind of need it within the doc itself. Thanks for helping me narrow down where the problem is!

Comment: I'll be happy to help you with any other errors you encounter.

Comment: just make sure to check the "correct" button (check mark) by whoever you thought was right and gave you the correct solution.